# Need help with rails model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I know there is alot of documentation out there on this stuff, but I can't seem to transform the associations in my head into rails even though the setup seems pretty simple.

We start with the user model. Each user potentially has_many addresses, phone numbers and (real estate) seller_listings while each seller_listing has one user, address and phone number.

Right now, this is what i have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seller_listings
  has_many :phone_numbers
  has_many :addresses


class SellerListing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :phone_number


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user


class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user


mysql> desc seller_listings;
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| user_id                  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| address_id               | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| phone_number_id          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
|...snip...

mysql> desc addresses;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| user_id    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| address1   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
|...snip...

mysql> desc phone_numbers;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| user_id    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
|...snip...
```

This all kind of works but I feel like it is wrong. When creating a seller_listing for a new user, I have to create then build the address and phone number kinda like so:

```
# User
if user = User.find_by_email(args['user']['email'])
  user.update_attributes(:first_name => args['user']['first_name'],
                         :last_name  => args['user']['last_name'])
else
  new_password = User.generate_new_password
  user = User.create(:password   => new_password, :confirmation_password => new_password,
                     :email      => args['user']['email'],
                     :first_name => args['user']['first_name'],
                     :last_name  => args['user']['last_name'])
end

# Address
addr = user.addresses.find_or_create_by_address1_and_zip(args['address']['address1'], args['address']['zip'])

# Phone Number
phone = user.phone_numbers.find_or_create_by_number(args['phone_number']['number'])

user.save!
```

Then once I get the user, I can create the seller listing:

```
SellerListing.create!(:user_id => user.id, :address_id => addr.id, :phone_number_id => phone.id)
```

Like I said, this all kinda works but I am trying to clean up the code by using accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :address, :phone_number in seller_listing but this doesn't work I assume because seller_listing currently has belongs_to :user, :address and :phone_number.

So, I have obviously botched the model association and could use some help if anybody out there has some suggestions.

[edited with after-thought]
Is the solution to add has_one :user, :address and :phone_number to seller listing and then when creating do something like:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > sl=SellerListing.new
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > sl.user.build("last_name"=>"Bar", "first_name"=>"Foo", "email"=>"foobar@example.com")
<repeat for address and phone number>
```

Comment: rails provides find_or_create method, very convenient. Will spare you your first if/else

Comment: Your SellerListing class would make more sense to me if it has_one :address and has_one :phone_number. I'm not sure what you find offensive about the code, but when you grow allergic to code (as you obviously have done), try moving it to the model(s) and take that opportunity to clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for me was polymorphic association. Here are my notes regarding the fix I employed:

### Polymorphic Associations

User has many seller listings, addresses and phone numbers
Seller Listing has one address and one phone number

Database Changes:

1. Addresses Table

   ```
   add_column :address_context_id, :integer, :null => false
   add_column :address_context_type, :string, :null => false
   ```
2. Phone Numbers Table

   ```
   add_column :phone_number_context_id, :integer, :null => false
   add_column :phone_number_context_type, :string, :null => false
   ```
3. populate new cols/backfil

Model Associations

1. Address

   ```
   belongs_to :address_context, :polymorphic => true
   ```
2. Phone Number

   ```
   belongs_to :phone_number_context, :polymorphic => true
   ```
3. User

   ```
   has_many :addresses, :as => :address_context
   has_many :phone_numbers, :as => :phone_number_context
   ```
4. Seller Listing

   ```
   has_one :address, :as => :address_context
   has_one :phone_number, :as => :phone_number_context
   ```

Helpful sites

http://media.railscasts.com/videos/154_polymorphic_association.mov

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

http://blog.opensteam.net/past/2008/11/26/polymorphic_controller_nested_routes_polymorphic